# PDI or mysqldump to extract data without blocking the database nor getting inconsistent data?

Tags: pentaho, mysql, kettle

I have an ETL process that will run periodically. I was using kettle (PDI) to extract the data from the source database and copy it to a stage database. For this I use several transformations with table input and table output steps. However, I think I could get inconsistent data if the source database is modified during the process, since this way I don't get a snapshot of the data. Furthermore, I don't know if the source database would be blocked. This would be a problem if the extraction takes some minutes (and it will take them). The advantage of PDI is that I can select only the necessary columns and use timestamps to get only the new data.

By the other hand, I think mysqldump with --single-transaction allows me to get the data in a consistent way and don't block the source database (all tables are innodb). The disadventage is that I would get innecessary data.

Can I use PDI, or I need mysqldump?

PD: I need to read specific tables from specific databases, so I think xtrabackup it's not a good option.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I think I could get inconsistent data if the source database is modified during the process, since this way I don't get a snapshot of the data

I think "Table Input" step doesn't take into account any modifications that are happening when you are reading. Try a simple experiment:

Take a .ktr file with a single table input and table output. Try loading the data into the target table. While in the middle of data load, insert few records in the source database. You will find that those records are not read into the target table. *(note i tried with postgresql db and the number of rows read is : 1000000)*

Now for your question, i suggest you using PDI since it gives you more control on the data in terms of versioning, sequences, SCDs and all the DWBI related activities. PDI makes it easier to load to the stage env. rather than simply dumping the entire tables.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: What I mean is that all the process takes for a while and some modifications can be done between the first and the last tables are copied, so it's possible that the first table wasn't updated but another table does. So I could have a register in a table that makes reference to somehting that doesn't exist. For example if I add a worker to a new factory, but the factories table have already been copied without the new factory or, the opposite, this factory is closed and the worker is moved to another factory but the workers table have already been copied and the closed factory is deleted.

Comment: @vjsp90 If you are fetching the records from source to different tables and if there is not relations b/w the two tables while doing so, you can try parallel loading of the tables. what i meant by relation is that.. if your last table is not dependnt on the load of the first table; you cn try parallel loading of the data.!!!

Comment: Yes, I would prefer the parallel load, but I always get errors (these change, not are the same, generally duplicate keys) in different transformations (DDL operations I think). If I launch them sequentially, no errors happen.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting point. If you do all the table inputs in one transformation then at least they all start at same time but whilst likely to be consistent it's not guaranteed.

There is no reason you can't use pdi to orchestrate the process AND use mysql dump.  In fact for bulk insert or extract it's nearly always better to use the vendor provided tools.

Comment: In fact I use mysql  into a shell script step. The problem is that I have to copy everything and that would take each time longer beacuase I can't use timestamp with the dump.